# The target "TypeScriptClean" does not exist in the project

Tags: typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional. When I build, I am getting a lot of TypeScript-related errors even though I don't have any typescript in my solution. The main one is:

`The target "TypeScriptClean" does not exist in the project.`

However, there are no references to anything called "TypeScriptClean" - or typescript at all - in my solution.

I also get:

`The target "CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig" does not exist in the project.`

Both these errors are occurring in the file Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets.

Anyone know what is going on here? I basically can't build anything in Visual Studio.

Comment: i am having same problem, did you find any solution? thanks in advance

Comment: I think I ended up reinstalling visual studio, sadly.

Comment: thanks @tuseau,  As future reference adding following lines at project file it resolved my errors.
 <Target Name="TypeScriptClean" DependsOnTargets="PreComputeCompileTypeScript">
    <Delete Files="@(GeneratedJavascript)" />
  </Target>

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf8db2ce-4a4d-4084-93a7-ca94c9bf6ce2/visual-studio-2013-update-3-breaks-typescript-for-visual-studio-2012?forum=vssetup

Comment: Big thanks to Deepak - solved my problem in 1 minute!!

Answer (score 7):

I added this to my .jsproj file and it worked. at least it gets past this issue and my project builds again. It's just an empty target, since I do not use typescript.

```
<Target Name="TypeScriptClean">
</Target>
```

I do not see where the typescript version is located for my older cordova project.

Answer (score 2):

in visual studio 2017

changing the typescript version to `Use latest available` on the project properties fixed the issue

[image: use latest]

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solve the problem.

- > 1) Create a new cordova project.
- > 2) Install all of the plugins that are installed in your current app.
- > 3) Delete the **www** folder from your NEW project.
- > 4) Copy the **www** folder from your OLD project and place it in the NEW project.
- > 4) Clean the solution (from the build menu)
- > 5) Now finally... build your app!

This always works for me when ever i run into random system issues.

*Remember, if you installed any 3rd party plugins you may need to re-install them before your app is fully functional again.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to make sure I'm debugging/running the project as "Debug x64" and not "Debug Mixed Platforms".